# Forcing the Unit Test project to use the linked web.config file from the ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, unit-testing, app-config

When I unit test the Business Layer project associated with my WinForms app, in my UnitTest project I include an app.config that's linked from the Winforms project.  This way, if I change anything in the EXE's app.config, it'll be reflected in my Unit Test.

I'd like to do the same with my ASP.NET projects, however, they use web.config, thus I can't simply link it to the UnitTest project.

So short of having a pre-build step that copies the web.config into UnitTest project's app.config, how can I get around this issue?

Comment: I try not to rely on configuration on the file system and usually mock the configuration interfaces with test values but the only way I've done this so far is with the post build rename step.

Comment: One other possible way is to take out some of the config sections and make those files linked in from the asp.net project, keeping app or web.config thin. In web.config: `<log4net configSource="Config\Log4Net.config" />
  <connectionStrings configSource="Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
  <castle configSource="Config\Dependencies.config" />
  <appSettings configSource="Config\AppSettings.config" />`. Then just have own copy of app.config in your unit tests.

Comment: @LukeHutton That's actually a pretty good idea.  I didn't realize .config files had what is essentially include functionality.